# Perform Query Based On Day Of The Week

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a piece of code that depending on the day of the week will return a piece of information from a sql column (which is specified by the day of the week) I currently have a piece of verbose code which goes like this.

```
 public void ErrorTest()
{
    using (ScraperSetupEntities context = new ScraperSetupEntities())
    {
        int collectionavg;
        string today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        if (today == "Sunday")
        {
            collectionavg = context.FourWeekCollectionReports.First().FourWeekSundayCollected;
        }
        if (today == "Monday")
        {
            collectionavg = context.FourWeekCollectionReports.First().FourWeekMondayCollected;
        }   
        // etc etc for every day of the week
    }
}
```

I know in t-sql I could have a literal string and append the day of the week to the "FourWeek" + today +"Collected"and then run the string as a query but I can't figure out how to do something similar in c#. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using a SWITCH statement?

Comment: Can you `First()` object have a method that returns a `collectionAvg`?  For instance, `int GetFourWeekCollectedByDay(string dayName)`?  Whether you're using interfaces or inheritance, there's no way of getting around a bunch of `if-else-if` or `switch`/`case`.

Comment: Not with this design, no.  But you should be using a switch statement.  And you shouldn't be calling ToString on an enum to do comparisons with it.  Use the DayOfWeek enumeration to compare it to DateTime.DayOfWeek.

Comment: Why call `DayOfWeek.ToString()`, why not just use `DayOfWeek` then use the enum in your if statements?

Answer (score 1):

Make it a function...

You can use the Where() function from Linq to select the proper day from you WeekCollection.

Then you can use the Select() function from Linq again to return the average collection count.

```
public int GetCollectionAvgFromDay(ScraperSetupEntities context, string DayOfWeek)
{
    return context.FourWeekCollectionReports.First().Where(x => x.Day == DayOfWeek).Select(x => x.CollectionAvg);
}
```

Skeleton of what the `WeekCollectionReport` should contain:

```
public class WeekCollectionReport
{
    public string Day {get; set;}
    public int CollectionAvg {get; set;}
}
```

And to call it, just do :

```
public void ErrorTest()
{
    using (ScraperSetupEntities context = new ScraperSetupEntities())
    {
        int collectionavg;
        string today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        collectionavg = GetCollectionAvgFromDay(context, today);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really get away with doing this unless you want to change the design. You can mode the code to your model if you just don't want to make you code smaller / cleaner

e.g.

```
public class Report
{
    public int SundayAvg { get; set; }
    public int MondayAvg { get; set; }
    public int TuesdayAvg { get; set; }

    //new property that just returns Todays average. 
    public int TodayAverage => GetTodayAverage();


    public int GetTodayAverage()
    {
        switch (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return SundayAvg;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return MondayAvg;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return TuesdayAvg;
             ...
            default:
                //How the hell did that happen;
                return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

...Then you can just ask for `TodayAverage`

```
List<Report> report = new List<Report>();
report.Add(new Report() { SundayAvg = 1, MondayAvg = 2, TuesdayAvg = 3 });

var a = report.First().TodayAverage;
```